# MYSQL C API : how do I use mysql_stmt_bind_result when I ignore the number of fields on the result?

Tags: mysql, c

When I use a prepared statement on mysql c api, I can receive the row result on the bound results if I use : **mysql_stmt_bind_result**.

However, this function requires me to prepare a MYSQL_BIND result for each field I recover from the database.

The problem is, how do I use it if I ignore the number of fields? Like a result from:

> select * from unknownFieldNumberTable

Comment: you can't. if you're binding, you're essentially setting up pointers from variables you've already created, to the matching locations of wherever the query results go. it's not the mysql library's job to create new vars for you.

Comment: yes, I was afraid of that. 
Then, how do I use a statement wich gives me diferent field size?
To my understanding, I need to bind the values for the statement to work:
"select * from users where id=?" requires me to set up bindings to satisfy the statement.

Comment: `select *` is usually a bad idea anyways. you seldom need ALL of the fields int he table, which means you're forcing the db/client to process a bunch of data which just thrown away anyways. do a specific `select field1, field2,....` for whatever you really do need, and set up bindings for those.

Comment: ok thank you very much

Comment: You could use `mysql_fetch_fields` to retrieve information for all the fields of the given table before preparing the statement, then set up a dynamic bindings array based on that information.  But Marc B is right - you don't want to just select *everything* without knowing how it will be processed.